# Key vault authentication for .net console app

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, azure-keyvault, identity-management

I am using Az key vault to retrieve Client Secret to Authentication. But when I run my console app using visual studio it return Client Secret based on the account I logged into the Visual Studio.
But I try to execute the .exe , it give me error

-Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot

- EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot
- WorkloadIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The workload options are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/workloadidentitycredential/troubleshoot
- ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity endpoint.
- Visual Studio Token provider can't be accessed at C:\Users\Rahul Kaushik\AppData\Local.IdentityService\AzureServiceAuth\tokenprovider.json
- Azure CLI not installed
- Az.Account module >= 2.2.0 is not installed.
- Azure Developer CLI could not be found.

I try to retrieve Client secret based on Client Id ,Secret Name , Tenant Id on a console app that is running on our onprim env. as .exe

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're encountering authentication issues while trying to retrieve a Client Secret from Azure Key Vault within your console application.
you can use the `ClientSecretCredential` class from the `Azure.Identity` namespace to authenticate.

*My `Program.cs` file*

```cs
    using Azure.Identity;
    using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
        
        class Program
        {
            static void Main()
            {
                string clientId = "********-****-****-****-************";
                string clientSecret = "****************************************";
                string tenantId = "********-****-****-****-************";
                string keyVaultUrl = "https://*******.vault.azure.net/";
                string secretName = "container";
        
                var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
                var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), clientSecretCredential);
        
                KeyVaultSecret secret = secretClient.GetSecret(secretName);
                string secretValue = secret.Value;
        
                Console.WriteLine($"Retrieved secret value: {secretValue}");
            }
        }
```

My `.csproj`

```cs
      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.10.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets" Version="4.5.0" />
      </ItemGroup>
```

**Secret Value in Vault**
[image]

**Output:**
[image]